# Js/CSS Images inside div with overflow:scroll prevent scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this strange bug

I have an div #page that I set to overflow :scroll, and i have the body with overflow:hidden because i want to prevent the pull down, and make the site feel like an "app"

```
html,body {
        height: 100vh;
        min-height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
}
#page {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
   }
```

pseudo page

```
<div #page>
<div .image>
<div .image>
<div .text>
<div .image>
<div .text>
</div>
```

inside the #page I have divs with images and text like in a long one-pager.

for some strange reason due to knows which conflict, when I scroll the #page it works well until I hover an **image** , not a text, contained in the page and in that case the scroll-wheel of my mouse wont scroll anymore. almost like the images overwrite the scroll.

I can't use pointer-events:none because of other reasons

Answer (score 0):

add in your code

```
window.onscroll = () => {
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

blocked the scroll

for reset:

```
window.onscroll = ()=>{
}
```